# Programmatically create SharePoint 2010 content type using XML definition file

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint-2010, contenttype

Is there any way to programmatically create a SharePoint 2010 content type using an XML definition file?
SPFields can be added in the following way:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<xml />");
```

Is there any similar way to programmatically add content types to a site collection/site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can programmatically create/add content types, but not using XML definition (as far as I'm aware). You have to construct it, add it to a content type collection, and manually add your field references to the field links collection.

A rough example would be:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPContentType contentType = new SPContentType(web.ContentTypes["Document"], web.ContentTypes, "Financial Document");
        web.ContentTypes.Add(contentType);
        contentType.Group = "Financial Content Types";
        contentType.Description = "Base financial content type";
        contentType.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(web.Fields.GetField("OrderDate")));
        contentType.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(web.Fields.GetField("Amount")));
        contentType.Update();
    }
}
```

You don't get to control the content type IDs this way though. I prefer using features as per Greg Enslow's response.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to use a feature definition and then activate the feature for your site collection. The xml for the feature will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <!-- Parent ContentType: Document (0x0101) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x0101000728167cd9c94899925ba69c4af6743e"
               Name="Financial Document"
               Group="Financial Content Types"
               Description="Base financial content type"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{1511BF28-A787-4061-B2E1-71F64CC93FD5}" Name="OrderDate" DisplayName="Date" Required="FALSE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC300F6}" Name="Amount" DisplayName="Amount" Required="FALSE"/>
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

See the full sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463449.aspx.

Was there a specific reason you were trying to use the object model instead?

Comment: I wanted to do it in the FeatureUpgrading event handler for my feature, together with the rest of the upgrade actions (to conform to the practices used in the current project), instead of using the ApplyElementManifests element.